# Confusion with time symmetry - pendulum example

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, symmetry-breaking, time-reversal-symmetry, arrow-of-time

If the classic nonlinear pendulum with friction equation is reviewed as example, in [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%27%27%2B2*0.021*x%27%2B0.2*%5Csin%28x%29%3D0%2C+x%280%29%3D%5Cpi%2F2%2C+x%27%280%29%3D0) it can be seen it have decaying solutions as expected:
$$\ddot{x}+2\cdot 0.021\,\dot{x}+0.2\sin(x)=0, x(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}, \dot{x}(0)=0 \tag{Eq. 1}\label{Eq. 1}$$

But following the analysis for [T-Symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry), under the transformation $\hat{t} \to - t$ the position and acceleration remains the same, but the velocity profile change in sign: this applied to \eqref{Eq. 1} shows it change under this transformation, so it not fulfill T-Symmetry.

If instead the standard [Drag force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)#At_high_velocity) $F_{\text{drag}}\propto (\dot{x})^2$ is used as is shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%27%27%2B0.021*%28x%27%29%5E2%2B0.2*%5Csin%28x%29%3D0%2C+x%280%29%3D%5Cpi%2F2%2C+x%27%280%29%3D0) for the equation:
$$\ddot{x}+0.021(\dot{x})^2+0.2\sin(x)=0, x(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}, \dot{x}(0)=0 \tag{Eq. 2}\label{Eq. 2}$$
their solution aren't showing the expected decay one can see on the experimental pendulums. This is commonly solve using an ansatz for the drag force $F_{\text{drag}}\propto \dot{x}|\dot{x}|$, which as can be seen [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%27%27%2B0.021*x%27*%7Cx%27%7C%2B0.2*%5Csin%28x%29%3D0%2C+x%280%29%3D%5Cpi%2F2%2C+x%27%280%29%3D0) for the equation:
$$\ddot{x}+0.021\dot{x}|\dot{x}|+0.2\sin(x)=0, x(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}, \dot{x}(0)=0 \tag{Eq. 3}\label{Eq. 3}$$
their solution are indeed having the expected decaying behavior for a pendulum with friction.

Since \eqref{Eq. 2} fulfills T-Symmetry but fails to proper model the pendulum with friction, but both \eqref{Eq. 1} and \eqref{Eq. 3} don't fulfill T-Symmetry but modeled properly the amplitudes, its look like for having a decaying behavior it was required to choose a differential equation that is not fulfilling the **time-reversal-symmetry**.

Since commonly is said that physics laws must fulfill T-Symmetry being the only counterexample the 2nd Law of Thermodynamics for the Entropy, I want to understand:

- What I am doing wrong here?, since the only solutions that shows having the experimentally observed decay are the differential equations which are not fulfilling T-Symmetry.
- Does this imply the kinetic energy must be $K=\frac{1}{2}mv|v|$ instead of $K=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$?

Comment: Time reversal does not mean that the world running backwards looks normal. See [How do we explain the motion of a time-reversed emptying balloon in vacuum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/692870/37364)

Answer (score 1):

A pendulum with friction is not T symmetric. It converts work to heat and increases entropy. So the time reverse will violate the 2nd law of thermodynamics by reducing entropy and converting heat to work with 100% efficiency.